# Rails + Twitter Bootstrap -- btn-mini btn-small not changing size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

Looking to use an icon for a delete button in a table, as shown below:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini"><i class="icon-white icon-trash"></i></a>
```

If I paste this code into a plain html page within my rails application, the btn-mini and btn-small seem to have no effect.

When I preview this button on http://www.plugolabs.com/twitter-bootstrap-button-generator/ it appears as I would expect.  Anyone familiar with why this may not be working?  I do not have any custom css files loading, just the bootstrap.

Also, I am running

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.4.0'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got similar problem and my solution was to change of gem. Have you tried to change your bootstrap gem? Check it out [this one](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at bootstrap-sass source in here:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_buttons.scss

The gem uses Bootstrap 3, so use:

.btn-xs instead of .btn-mini 
.btn-sm instead of .btn-small 
.btn-lg instead if .btn-large